# Ansible organization for a versioned product

Tags: ansible, versioning

I'm working in a company with a big code base with multiples products,
We use Ansible for our products deployments.
We have multiples shared roles and specific roles per product.
Each shared role is versioning and tagged,

Let's imagine product **X in version 1.0.0** and a product **Y in version 1.1.0**
and 2 shared roles A & B

X has a dependency on role A/B in version 1.0.0
Y has a dependency on role A in version 1.0.0 and role B in version 1.5.0

I'm working on my product X for a new major release 1.1.0
So I'm working too in Ansible to add multiples config files, remove some others, update the shared role **A**

But my version 1.0.0 is still in production, so it may require some adjustments for bugs. and It may need to update the ansible too.

Now is my problem.

When I release X:1.1.0 with the updated ansible, my playbooks are no more compatible with the 1.0.0 branch.

What's a good practice for handling ansible with a product life

It is good to have a role and tasks per version ?

```
tasks
  - main.yml
  - 1.0.0.yml
  - 1.1.0.yml
```

```
cat main.yml

---
include_tasks: {{product_version}}.yml


include_tasks: 1.1.0.yml
when : product_version >= 1.1.0
```

and in each version file contains the diff with the previous one ?

but for the 1.10.0, it will become a nightmare...

Do you have any experience for these uses cases ?

Comment: See [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we must assume that all roles are in their own git repositories.  (If they are not, fix that first.)  Also, the playbook that will do the installation is also in its own repository, along with a file called `roles/requirements.yml`.  (That is where Ansible Tower expects it to be.)

A particular version of the installation playbook repo will have a particular `roles/requirements.yml` file which will specify exactly what versions of what roles are needed to run that version of the playbook.

So, for product X, we have a `roles/requirements.yml` file that says,

```
- name: A
  src: git@gitlab.company.com:mygroup/A.git
  scm: git
  version: 1.0.0
- name: B
  src: git@gitlab.company.com:mygroup/B.git
  scm: git
  version: 1.0.0
```

And for product Y, we have a `roles/requirements.yml` file that says,

```
- name: A
  src: git@gitlab.company.com:mygroup/A.git
  scm: git
  version: 1.0.0
- name: B
  src: git@gitlab.company.com:mygroup/B.git
  scm: git
  version: 1.5.0
```

[Installing Roles with Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html)

Comment: Ok I see,     
actually, We have a unique Ansible repo with our all projects inside.  with all shared libs are the specifics roles per product
I think we need to split each project in a separate git repo , I can't ATM use an old product role